# Lock-free Tree Node Assignment in Preallocated Vector of Nodes

Tags: c++, multithreading, tree, openmp, lock-free

I'm currently trying to **multithread** the creation of a **tree** where the class which holds the tree preallocates a `std::vector` of `Node`s in a chunk of a particular size (conceptually the size is arbitrary). Additional chunks of `Node` are created only when necessary, this is because the tree quickly becomes very large and I wanted to avoid constantly using the `new` operator for time efficiency.

These vectors of `Node`s are defined as: `std::vector< std::vector< Node > > nodes`

`head` keeps track of the position within the inner vector and `chunkCount` keeps track of which outer vector is being used currently.

The vectors are resized in the constructor as:

```
nodes.resize( 1 );
nodes[chunkCount].resize( CHUNK_SIZE );
```

And a simplified version of `Node` would be:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int val;
    Node* subnodes[5];
} Node;
```

Creation of a new `Node` goes as follows:

```
void TreeClass::createNode( Node* node, short index, int val )
{
    omp_set_lock( &treeLock ); // treeLock belongs to TreeClass
    head++;
    if( head == CHUNK_SIZE ) {
        std::vector< Node > tempNodeVec( CHUNK_SIZE );
        nodes.push_back( tempNodeVec );
        chunkCount++;
        head = 0;
    }
    node->subnodes[index] = &( nodes[chunkCount][head] );
    omp_unset_lock( &treeLock );

    node->subnodes[index]->val = val;
}
```

This works perfectly fine. However my concern is that all but one thread is blocked when creating a node and this happens frequently so a lot of time is spent blocked or locking/unlocking `treeLock`, hence my desire to make this function **lock-free** but my attempts so far have failed.

Altering `head` and `chunkCount` are easy enough without the lock using `#pragma omp atomic` (or by using `std::atomic< int >`s), but it is the logic behind assuring that the `if( ... )` statement is executed only once and before any thread proceeds to assign the address of the child, i.e. to assure they use the correct/updated `chunkCount` and `head`.

One thought from reading about lock-free algorithms would be to use `std::atomic< Node* > subnodes[5]` in `Node` and perform a CAS operation waiting for the correctly updated `head` and `chunkCnt` but without knowing what would be "correct", how can I know what I'm waiting for?

Another (naive) idea was:

```
int myHead;
if( ++head == CHUNK_SIZE ) {
    std::vector< Node > tempNodeVec( CHUNK_SIZE );
    nodes.push_back( tempNodeVec );
    chunkCount++;
    myhead = head = 0;
} else {
    myhead = head;
    while( head > CHUNK_SIZE )
        myHead = ++head;
}
node->subnodes[index] = &( nodes[chunkCount][myHead] );
```

The idea being that only one thread goes into the `if( ... )` and until it has set `head` to 0, the rest will be stuck in the `else { ... }` but I can already see the **many problems with this approach**.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use a thread-private memory pool. To that end you can use an annotation like:

```
#pragma omp threadprivate(nodes)
```

Not only is that far simpler than trying to protect access to the shared memory pool, it will also likely be better for performance due to data locality.

Note: going lockfree based on atomics with your solution is impossible because `nodes[chunkCount]` - which is needed for every allocation - must always be protected from `nodes.push_back`.

Fully featured memory pooling is more complex, but as a little step, you can try using `std::deque`. It provides what you need without messing with two vectors - inserting elements in constant time while not invalidating pointers of existing elements. You have less control but it's a good start.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll look into thread-private memory. And `std::deque` looks to be a good idea for this project. Thanks again